# Edit custom object in react state

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a Map() object in my app state called myMap.
I need to edit a key of this map. So I create a map called newMyMap equels to  existing myMap object but with a key-value different.

When I call setState, setting myMap = newMyMap Ract insert new Map (myNewMap) intead delete old Map. How can manager this situation?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the code that has an issue?

Comment: Can you show some code? Maybe you are not overwriting the existing key

Answer (score 1):

I think you just don't understand how react state works.. it's just a object with keys and if you set some other key of course the other key is still there..

So if you want to change the "myMap" just assign new value to it.. like:

```
const newMyMap = Map({some: 'data'});

this.setState({
  myMap: newMyMap,
});
```

And you shouldn't modify the existing objects. If you need to just modify some object data, create new object from the old one like:

```
this.setState({
  myMap: Object.assign({}, myOldObject, {someProp: 'new value'}),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Have two Map object (or other type) with same value inside is different to have 2 equals object. Maybe I did not keep in mind this.